# How to run couchbase n1ql-command from powershell

Tags: powershell, couchbase, sql++

I'm trying to extract all the documents from a bucket and pipe them out to a file. I'm running this commmand:

```bsh
PS C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin> ./cbq --engine couchbase://localhost --user Administrator --password 'password' --script="SELECT * FROM `bucket.name`"
```

But Powershell expects something more and gives me newlines with `>>` at the start of each line after executing the command.

If I drop the --script=... I log into the cqb-shell, and running the command/script works fine, but  piping to file becomes difficult.

Do anyone have an idea of what's missing here? And how I can run the command from the terminal?

`PS C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin> ./cbq -v
 SHELL VERSION  : 2.0` on  Couchbase Community Edition 6.0.0 build 1693

Comment: I'm at a bit of a loss why this isn't working. I've tried this on my local machine and it seems to work okay. The only thing I can think of is that maybe Powershell is having trouble parsing the backticks `? I tried using backticks and I got an error response (but I didn't get the newlines as you are getting). Would you mind trying it sans backticks and see if that shakes anything loose?

Comment: Does there have to be backquotes around bucket.name?  The second one escapes the doublequote.  You can try doubling up on the backquotes, or use regular single quotes instead of that is a typo.

Comment: Sans backticks wont work, because the bucket contains a dot, single quoute `'` didnt work, but double backticks worked! Put it as an answer and I will mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer came in the comments:

Put double back ticks around the bucket name, since the single back tick escaped the double quote

```
PS C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin> ./cbq --engine couchbase://localhost --user Administrator --password 'password' --script="SELECT * FROM ``bucket.name``"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use --file , --output options

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/tools/cbq-shell.html

https://dzone.com/articles/mastering-the-couchbase-n1ql-shell-scripting

Comment: The problem is running the shell-command and it expecting something more, the same with adding --file/output. BUT this led me to discover `\REDIRECT file.json` that lets me output from the cbq-shell instead of the terminal with -s